# how to import data from two tables into one table in another database

Tags: sql, sql-server

i tried to make backup from a database so i want to import data from two tables into one table in another database 
i created database whith the same columns with the same types but i got error

i want to copy data from examiners and results to enthar_backup

[image]

and this is my code

```
Select      T_Examiners.Ex_Barcode,
            T_Examiners.sold_id,
            T_Examiners.Ex_name,
            T_Results.Rs_Barcode,
            T_Results.Rs_Value,
            T_Results.Rs_Note,
            T_Results.Rs_ClassNo 
Into        ENTHAR_DB In 'ent7ar_backup.mdb' 
From        T_Results 
Inner Join  T_Examiners On  T_Examiners.Ex_Barcode = T_Results.Rs_Barcode
```

i got error near IN what i should do ?

Comment: You can't just set the target of an insert statement to be a file. That doesn't make any sense at all. You would need to use a linked server for this type of thing. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx Or are both databases on the same server? If that is the case you just access the other database with 3 part naming.

Comment: This syntax is a mess... it's not even close to correct.  You can neither use `INTO` nor `IN` the way you're attempting to use it.

Comment: yes the same server so what i can do ?

Comment: Have you attempted to do this backup from two tables into one table interactively using the SQL Server Management Studio? If not it might be helpful to do so before attempting to write a program that does this.

Comment: i want to do this by a program , what is the wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like both databases are in the same server you can use the `[Database].[schema].[tablename]` to insert data like this:

```
INSERT INTO ENTHAR_DB.dbo.ent7ar_backup
(
    Ex_Barcode,
    sold_id,
    Ex_name,
    Rs_Barcode,
    Rs_Value,
    Rs_Note,
    Rs_ClassNo
)
SELECT      T_Examiners.Ex_Barcode,
            T_Examiners.sold_id,
            T_Examiners.Ex_name,
            T_Results.Rs_Barcode,
            T_Results.Rs_Value,
            T_Results.Rs_Note,
            T_Results.Rs_ClassNo 
FROM        T_Results 
JOIN  T_Examiners ON  T_Examiners.Ex_Barcode = T_Results.Rs_Barcode
```

Comment: string or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
i got this error

Comment: @Amr that is because you have data in one of the source columns that is longer than the destination allows. This is NOT a flaw of this code, it is a problem because of your table structures.

Comment: It must be your `Rs_Value` column on the `T_Results` table it is `decimal(10,1)` and on the `ent7ar_backup` table it is `decimal(10, 0)`

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have the same column order on the INSERT clause and the SELECT that's why you're getting that error. The answer from bwilliamson has that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the SQL select statement at:

```
Into ENTHAR_DB In 'ent7ar_backup.mdb'
```

You don't name the file name to select into.  I would probably write it as an Insert statement rather than a Select Into.  See below:

```
INSERT INTO [ENTHAR_DB].[DBO].[ent7ar_backup](Ex_name,Rs_Barcode, sold_id,  
            Rs_Classno, Rs_Note, Rs_Value,Ex_Barcode)
Select      T_Examiners.Ex_Barcode,
            T_Examiners.sold_id,
            T_Examiners.Ex_name,
            T_Results.Rs_Barcode,
            T_Results.Rs_Value,
            T_Results.Rs_Note,
            T_Results.Rs_ClassNo 
From        T_Results 
Inner Join  T_Examiners On  T_Examiners.Ex_Barcode = T_Results.Rs_Barcode
```

Comment: string or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
i got this error

Comment: @Amr that is because you have data in one of the source columns that is longer than the destination allows. This is NOT a flaw of this code, it is a problem because of your table structures.

Comment: The order you supplied does not match the order of the columns.  Please use the following:

Comment: Select
            T_Examiners.Ex_name,
            T_Results.Rs_Barcode,
            T_Examiners.sold_id,
            T_Results.Rs_ClassNo,
            T_Results.Rs_Note,
            T_Results.Rs_Value,
            T_Examiners.Ex_Barcode

Comment: Either way, match the order of the Insert part with the order of the Select part.